# Add a title to a ul-navigation

Tags: html, css

I want to add a title to a group of some navigation-elements. The result should look like this one: https://jsfiddle.net/cd8tb9z3/1/

As I use an unordered list, I don't know where and how to add the title-element.

```css
   nav {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: .3em 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
   }
   nav > ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: .25em;
    color: #555;
    margin: 0 0 0 .5em;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border-radius: 5px;
   }
   nav > ul > li {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
    font-size: .5em;
    margin: .5em 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 4em;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    position: relative;

   }
   nav ul li i {
       font-size: 3em !important;
   }
   nav > ul > li > ul {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2.5em;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    display: none;
   }

   .button-arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #B4B4B4;
       margin: 0 auto;
       position: relative;
       bottom: -7px;
   }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i><br>New</li>
    <li>
     <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i><br>
     Save<br>
     <span class="button-arrow-down"></span>
     <ul>
      <li>Subelement 1</li>
      <li>Subelement 2</li>
      <li>Subelement 3</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put `<span class="nav-button-group-title">Image-Editor</span>` inside the `ul` list (as first element).
Working code:

```css
nav {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: .3em 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
nav > ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: .25em;
    color: #555;
    margin: 0 0 0 .5em;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
nav > ul > li {
    font-family:"Source Sans Pro";
    font-size: .5em;
    margin: .5em 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 4em;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li i {
    font-size: 3em !important;
}
nav > ul > li > ul {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2.5em;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    display: none;
}
.button-arrow-down {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #B4B4B4;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -7px;
}
.nav-button-group-title {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:"Source Sans Pro";
    font-size: .7em;
    color: #555;
    padding: 0 .5em;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <span class="nav-button-group-title">Image-Editor</span>       
        <li><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>
            <br>New</li>
        <li> <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>
            <br>Save
            <br> <span class="button-arrow-down"></span>

            <ul>
                <li>Subelement 1</li>
                <li>Subelement 2</li>
                <li>Subelement 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: That's invalid HTML. Only `li` are allowed as direct children of `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

I've rejigged the answer from @wazaaaap as only `li` are allowed as direct children of `ul`

Put the title `span` as the first element inside the `nav`.

```css
nav {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: .3em 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
nav > ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: .25em;
    color: #555;
    margin: 0 0 0 .5em;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
nav > ul > li {
    font-family:"Source Sans Pro";
    font-size: .5em;
    margin: .5em 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 4em;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li i {
    font-size: 3em !important;
}
nav > ul > li > ul {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2.5em;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    display: none;
}
.button-arrow-down {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #B4B4B4;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -7px;
}
.nav-button-group-title {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:"Source Sans Pro";
    font-size: .7em;
    color: #555;
    padding: 0 .5em;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav>
  <span class="nav-button-group-title">Image-Editor</span>  
    <ul>
             
        <li><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>
            <br>New</li>
        <li> <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>
            <br>Save
            <br> <span class="button-arrow-down"></span>

            <ul>
                <li>Subelement 1</li>
                <li>Subelement 2</li>
                <li>Subelement 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: But I need the title inside of the ul-container, as there will be multiple container like this.

Comment: Would it be possible to use the first li-element of the ul-list as the title? That means to format the first element as a block element with 100%width of the complete ul-list... What would this be a reasonable html-markup? Otherwise I could do something like: `<section><h1>Title</h1><ul>...</ul></section>` with section-element as the grouping one...

Comment: That could work. It's not exactly semantic though. I'd be inclined to  make the title an `li` and have the icons as a submenu of that.